# Android: Ogg Files Not Looping while set as Ringtone

Tags: android, infinite-loop, ogg

I am developing a SoundBoard application. From my application when I set any ogg file as default ringtone. They stop playing once while ringing. I tried Adding ANDROID_LOOP metadata set to true. But it sets the sound to play in loop forever in my soundboard. Is there any alternate way to loop ogg while ringing? Thanks.